# Alternative of MonkeyTalkIDE Tool for mobile testing?

Tags: android, ios, testing, automation, monkeytalk

I installed MonkeyTalk Tool from https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/ .
After downloading & installing the tool, its not working.

Two times i deleted & download again but still its not working.
Stuck on the desktop even when i try to close it i am unable to close this application.

so i am looking for any alternative of Monkey Talk Tool which is open source & easy to use.

If any one knows please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is not working with you. If any specifics you can tell me so that I can help you with it. Ranorex is one which you can use.

Comment: i had some problem with SDK but now it sorted but i haven't start the test. Is there any coding is required in Monkeytalk? Does it support in window 8?

Comment: It supports only iOS and android. No coding is required in MonkeyTalk until and unless you don't want to write scripts of your own.